# Making a website work on a tablet and smartphone

Tags: html, css

I am in the stages of developing a website for my business startup, and yet I'm practicing programming both on and off of my computer science studies in college by doing this. Here is the website url:

http://www.sampsonvision.com/

If you view it on a desktop, it actually looks good, but when you view it on a tablet and a smartphone, it does not look good because on the tablet, the text is squished in, and on a phone, the text is not visible and you can't scroll to the side. Here are my website files, in this zip folder:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZPyNRv7C3hU0hWa1lsajRxMVE/edit?usp=sharing

May you help me find what I'm missing from this. The viewport tags aren't even working. A lot of what you see has been configured in the style.css document. I'll need some help. Our first big release is due late November 2015.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Comment: google media queries, they are your responsive layout best friend

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in line 17 of your CSS:

```
div.mainmenu {
width: 550px;
height: 13px;
position: inherit;
 right: 500px; 
bottom: 30px;
}
```

Because `right` is set, it will push content over no matter what size your window is. So if it's a small window, it's still going to push it over 500px. That's why it's completely off the screen in mobile and off partly in tablet.

Any time you have fixed pixel dimensions you will encounter this issue. You can use media queries to target to compensate. For instance,

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
.mainmenu{
right:0;
}
}
```

Comment: I managed to get the iPhone mode squared away, but for the Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro 12.2, portrait mode is out of the question. I'm attempting to make modifications where the text is not overlapping the 3Point Animation logo. Could you please help me get this fixed. The updated code is in this file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ZPyNRv7C3hRzRNdGdSRHBLZG8/edit?usp=sharing